# SQL Server - SELECT ROWS have consecutive orders

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a price schedule table for rooms Day by Day. My table like below.

```
RoomId        Date(DD.MD.YY)       RemainingQuota      Price
-----------|------------------|--------------------|----------
1           1.5.2017            5                     10.00
1           1.6.1017            0                     10.00
1           1.7.1017            3                     12.00
1           1.8.1017            0                     10.00
1           1.9.1017            6                     15.00
.....
.....
```

Input params are

```
@CheckIn date = CAST('1.5.2017' AS date)
@CheckOut date = CAST('1.8.2017' AS date)
```

I need to select 3 consecutive dates which have `RemainingQuota` greater then zero and first date closest `@CheckIn`

I know the CTE recursive solution. However it comes me very expensive. Does any one know a cheap solution?

Thank you.

### SOLVED

I have solved the case by myself without using CTE. Here is complate test code.

```
    BEGIN /*PREPARE SAMPLE DATA*/    
    CREATE TABLE #priceSchedules(
        RoomId int not null,
        [Date] date not null,
        Quota int not null,
        Price decimal(18,4) not null
    )

    INSERT INTO #priceSchedules
    select 
         RoomId = R.RoomId
        ,[Date] = D.[Date]
        ,Quota = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 5)
        ,Price = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 50)
        from
        (
            select top 100 
                RoomId = row_number() over(order by R.number)
            from master..spt_values R 
            ) R
        OUTER apply(
        select top 60 
        [Date] = cast(DATEADD(day, row_number() over(order by t1.number), getdate()) as date)
        from master..spt_values t1 
        ) D
    END

        BEGIN /*PARAMETERS*/
        DECLARE @RoomId int = 5,
                @CheckIn date = cast(dateadd(day, 3, getdate()) as date),
                @CheckOut date = cast(dateadd(day, 6, getdate()) as date);

        DECLARE @TotalNight int = datediff(day, @CheckIn, @CheckOut)
        END


        BEGIN /*QUERY */
        DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
        SET STATISTICS TIME ON; --FOR CHECK PERFORMANCE

        PRINT('-----------START SELECT---------------------------------')

        SELECT 
        * 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
            _P.*
            ,RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RoomId ORDER BY DayDiffFromCheckIn)
            FROM(
                SELECT 
                 P.RoomId
                ,StartDate = P.[Date]
                ,EndDate = MAX(P2.[Date])
                ,CalcDay = COUNT(*)
                ,DayDiffFromCheckIn = CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(day,P.[Date],@CheckIn)) AS INT)
                ,MinQuota = IIF(MIN(P.Quota) > MIN(P2.Quota) ,MIN(P2.Quota),MIN(P.Quota))
                ,TotalPrice = MIN(P.Price) + SUM(P2.Price)
                FROM #priceSchedules P
                JOIN #priceSchedules AS P2 ON P2.RoomId = P.RoomId AND P2.[Date] > P.[Date] AND P2.[Date] < DATEADD(day, @TotalNight ,P.[Date]) AND P2.Quota > 0
                WHERE P.RoomId = @RoomId AND P.Quota > 0 AND P.[Date] >= GETDATE()
                GROUP BY P.RoomId,P.[Date]
                HAVING(COUNT(*) = (@TotalNight) - 1) -- -1 is for first row
            ) _P
        )__P
        WHERE __P.RowNo < 3 -- for top 3 option colsest to @CheckIn date

        PRINT('-----------END SELECT---------------------------------')

        --SELECT * FROM #priceSchedules
        DROP TABLE #priceSchedules
        SET STATISTICS TIME OFF; 
        END
```

Comment: what version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: It is OK to answer your own question. Just put the answer part as the "answer", not in the question body. Then you can accept your own answer. Thus everybody will know that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLVED

I have solved the case by myself without using CTE. Here is complate test code.

```
    BEGIN /*PREPARE SAMPLE DATA*/    
    CREATE TABLE #priceSchedules(
        RoomId int not null,
        [Date] date not null,
        Quota int not null,
        Price decimal(18,4) not null
    )

    INSERT INTO #priceSchedules
    select 
         RoomId = R.RoomId
        ,[Date] = D.[Date]
        ,Quota = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 5)
        ,Price = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 50)
        from
        (
            select top 100 
                RoomId = row_number() over(order by R.number)
            from master..spt_values R 
            ) R
        OUTER apply(
        select top 60 
        [Date] = cast(DATEADD(day, row_number() over(order by t1.number), getdate()) as date)
        from master..spt_values t1 
        ) D
    END

        BEGIN /*PARAMETERS*/
        DECLARE @RoomId int = 5,
                @CheckIn date = cast(dateadd(day, 3, getdate()) as date),
                @CheckOut date = cast(dateadd(day, 6, getdate()) as date);

        DECLARE @TotalNight int = datediff(day, @CheckIn, @CheckOut)
        END


        BEGIN /*QUERY */
        DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS;
        SET STATISTICS TIME ON; --FOR CHECK PERFORMANCE

        PRINT('-----------START SELECT---------------------------------')

        SELECT 
        * 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
            _P.*
            ,RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RoomId ORDER BY DayDiffFromCheckIn)
            FROM(
                SELECT 
                 P.RoomId
                ,StartDate = P.[Date]
                ,EndDate = MAX(P2.[Date])
                ,CalcDay = COUNT(*)
                ,DayDiffFromCheckIn = CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(day,P.[Date],@CheckIn)) AS INT)
                ,MinQuota = IIF(MIN(P.Quota) > MIN(P2.Quota) ,MIN(P2.Quota),MIN(P.Quota))
                ,TotalPrice = MIN(P.Price) + SUM(P2.Price)
                FROM #priceSchedules P
                JOIN #priceSchedules AS P2 ON P2.RoomId = P.RoomId AND P2.[Date] > P.[Date] AND P2.[Date] < DATEADD(day, @TotalNight ,P.[Date]) AND P2.Quota > 0
                WHERE P.RoomId = @RoomId AND P.Quota > 0 AND P.[Date] >= GETDATE()
                GROUP BY P.RoomId,P.[Date]
                HAVING(COUNT(*) = (@TotalNight) - 1) -- -1 is for first row
            ) _P
        )__P
        WHERE __P.RowNo < 3 -- for top 3 option colsest to @CheckIn date

        PRINT('-----------END SELECT---------------------------------')

        --SELECT * FROM #priceSchedules
        DROP TABLE #priceSchedules
        SET STATISTICS TIME OFF; 
        END
```